# Symfony ignores overriding settings and always uses default

Tags: symfony1

I have a very odd issue with symfony. There are default settings in the lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config/settings.yml some of which should be overridden in app/frontend/modules/config/settings.yml (standard_helpers) and some in plugins/[pluginname]/config/settings.yml (enabled_modules) but as the result in the cache/frontend/dev/config/config_settings.yml.php I see the default settings for enabled_modules ( 'sf_enabled_modules' => array (  0 => 'default',)) and there is wrong set of helpers.

I checked everything many times, outputted array with config options from the related class, and cleared the cache a hundred of times. Please help!

I'm using PHP: 5.2.9 on Mac OS 10.5

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question. The problem is php version. Don't ever use 5.2.9 with symfony :)

Comment: More info please. Sounds interesting